# Query all posts in a given taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, tax-query

For sure it's very simple, but I can not figure out how to do this.

I need to query all posts that has a specific taxonomy set. Like this:

```
$query03 = array( 
'numberposts' => 5, 
'post_type' => array(
    'video'
    ), 
'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => **all_the_terms_in_taxonomy**
        )
    ) 
);
```

I want set the `terms` field a wildcard. I know I could populate `terms` fild with an array, but the list is very very long and I'm worried about weight of the query.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried simply omitting the `'terms'` key from the `'tax_query'` array?

```
$query03 = array( 
    'numberposts' => 5, 
    'post_type' => array(
        'video'
    ), 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product',
            'field' => 'slug'
        )
    ) 
);
```

Alternately, I wouldn't really worry about the weight of the query. The resulting query will be what it will be, regardless of how complex the query args, or how big the query args array. So, I would recommend just pulling in all of your terms via [**`get_terms`**](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_terms):

```
<?php get_terms( $taxonomy, $args ); ?>
```

You can use it directly in your query args array, by setting `'fields'` to `'ids'`, which will return an array of term IDs, rather than an array of term objects):

```
$query03 = array( 
    'numberposts' => 5, 
    'post_type' => array(
        'video'
    ), 
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product',
            'field' => 'id',
            'terms' => get_terms( 'product', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) )
        )
    ) 
);
```

#### Edit

Alternate '`tax_query`', using term slugs instead of IDs:

```
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => get_terms( 'product', array( 'fields' => 'names' ) )
        )
    )
```

Comment: 1. Omitting term field woudln't help. 2. Did you mean `'field' => 'id',` ;-)?

Comment: Nope; `get_terms()` args array uses ['`fields` => `ids`'](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.2/wp-includes/taxonomy.php#L1184).

Comment: Where did I wrote **fields**?

Comment: Which code block are you referring to with respect to `'field'`? The `tax_query` array uses `'field'` (singular), but `get_terms()` args array uses `'fields'` (plural).

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean now. **Yes**: the `'tax_query'` needs to use `'field' => 'id'`, because in that case, `'field'` corresponds to the *term*, not to the *taxonmy*. [Refer to the Codex for `'tax_query'`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters): "**field (string) - Select taxonomy term by ('id' or 'slug')**"

Comment: Do **taxonomy term** is *corresponds to the taxonomy, not to the terms* ? Man who is English native speeker here you or me? Code you posted wouldn't return any post.

Comment: Calm down. :) I've just not had enough coffee yet this morning. I had already edited both the comment and the answer accordingly.

Comment: my comment was before you edit yours =)

Comment: "*my comment was before you edit yours =)*" - Not possible, actually. Previous comments cannot be edited once subsequent comments have been left. :)

Comment: Ok. Not posible.

Comment: The get_terms solution works, but the query is very very huge. WP have to, first, retrieve all the terms in a taxonomy, then compare the terms with the main query. Any lighter solution?